# Customizing a block

Tags: 7, blocks

Is there a way to customize a block as follows?

```
label   input text box(the editor can input the content)
label   input text box(the editor can input the content)
label   input text box(the editor can input the content)
image(the editor can upload a image)
```

Comment: Are you asking for the output of block created by a module you maintain, or by a module maintained from somebody else?

Comment: nope,i want to do a widget (which use in wordpress) [http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets). the widget have an admin interface.so the editor  can edit the form content, this widget can invoke by the template file.

Comment: i know i can add a block, and put the html code into it. then invoke the block in the place where i want to use it.
in order to maintain it conveniently and make the editor changes the form content easily ,so i want to do a admin interface to the form. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a node-type with these fields and embed the node form in a block.

Comment: but when i publish the content, there will be create a node. i don't want to create a node. i only want to invoke the block at other place., thank you

Comment: why are you putting a form in a block if you don't want people to use it?

Comment: the content of the form is invoked by the node page or the page--fornt.tpl.php page. in order to maintain it conveniently and make the editor changes the form content easily ,so i want to do a admin interface to the form. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to look at something like [Node Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) which lets you use all the power of CCK when building blocks. Technically you do end up with a node and a block, but I don't think that's a problem. Just use something like [Search Restrict](http://drupal.org/project/search_restrict) to stop people from ever finding the node.